# Odoo 10 Server Error when installing POS addon

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo-10, traceback

**--THE PROBLEM AT HAND--**

I am running Odoo 10.0 in a BSD jail on my FreeNAS 9.10.2 server.  When attempting to install the POS app, I receive an Odoo Server Error with the following traceback report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/local/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 410, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 484, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 337, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 235, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 848, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 918, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 802, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 710, in _tag_record
    id = self.env(context=rec_context)['ir.model.data']._update(rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1186, in _update
    record = record.create(values)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 353, in create
    return super(View, self).create(self._compute_defaults(values))
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3817, in create
    self._fields[key].determine_inverse(record)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 999, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 220, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 371, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3549, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3695, in _write
    self._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/usr/local/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1073, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Element '<xpath expr="//group[@name='inventory']//field[@name='categ_id']">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `product.normal.form`
[view_id: 1140, xml_id: n/a, model: product.template, parent_id: 298]
None" while parsing /usr/local/odoo/addons/product_multi_category/views/product_view.xml:4, near
<record id="product_normal_form_view_add_categids" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.normal.form</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
            <field eval="7" name="priority"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//group[@name='inventory']//field[@name='categ_id']" position="after">
                    <field name="categ_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

**--MY EVALUATION--**

What catches my attention, though, is near the end of the traceback; a `ParseError`.  In the details of the `ParseError`, the element for which it is parsing, has an extra attribute in the file it's parsing.  That is to say, that it is parsing for `<xpath expr="...'categ_id']">'` but the file being parsed contains, rather, `<xpath expr="...'categ_id']" position="after">`?

**--STEPS TAKEN--**

I edited the xml file in question, by removing the `position="after"` attribute from the `xpath` expression, before attempting to install the POS app again.  Unfortunately, the result was the same.

**--WHAT NEXT--**

What other steps can I take to remedy this situation?

**--EDIT #1--Further steps taken--**
I tried installing the app on another database hosted on the same Odoo server, and it installed with no issues on that database.  I still run into the server error when trying to install the POS app on the first database I tried.

**--EDIT #2--Success!--**
Steps I took which resolved the issue with helpful hints from the commenters.

1. Backup DB including assets using Odoo Database Management
2. Installed postgreSQL and Odoo Server on separate local machine
3. Restored Backup onto local Odoo Installation (For whatever reason, the Contacts view produced an error, but I ignored it and kept going)
4. Installed POS module successfully
5. Backup local DB including assets using Odoo Database Management
6. Restored Backup onto server Odoo Installation
7. Checked Contacts view.  No errors.  Installing and uninstalling modules functionality has been restored.

Success!

I am still uncertain as to what caused the issue in the first place.  Even upon restoring old backups would not allow me to install the POS module or any module for that matter.  Now, however; I can.

Comment: You should not have to edit any of the core files to be able to install. It's bad practice to make any changes to them at all. The `categ_ids` field is added after (according to the `xpath`) the normal `categ_id` field. It is erring because it can't find that field in the parent view (`product.product_template`). I'd suggest you use Developer Mode to find that view in `Settings > Technical > Views`. Take a look at the Inherited Views and see if anything is Replacing or otherwise changing the parent view.

Comment: You might have edited base addons because there is no such kind of view name in original base of odoo10 POS. So take a fresh odoo and try to start session in that. This might helps you to solve your issue. You can check in odoo runbot also to confirm your base.

Comment: @travisw, the views and parent views from what I can surmise when doing a side-by-side comparison of the two databases (the one where it was successful, and the one where it was not) are identical.  I realize the bad practice of making changes to the core files, but I wanted to see the effect of such a change.  Changes undone immediately after it was ascertained they had no effect.

Comment: @KevalMehta, all base addons are in their original form.  I used the same installation of Odoo on a different database, and was able to successfully install the addon for that database, but not the database for which I have need of the addon.